# Installing Windows XP from usb

Tags: windows-xp, usb-boot

So here's my story. I had windows Vista on my laptop, but as we all know, vista is terrible. So I installed ubuntu (and let the wubi installer delete windows completely). Now, after all this time, I 'd like to have windows XP back on my laptop. The problem is: my dvd drive is broken, so I have to use a USB boot. But then comes a new problem. Every time I try to run the usb boot, I get this error: bootmgr is missing.

A friend told me it's because I let ubuntu take over the entire laptop, and because of that, my HDD is not in the right format for me to install windows again..

Any ideas on how I could solve this? :/

Comment: Do you want to dual boot or replace Ubuntu with XP?

Comment: If your PC booted from USB it doesn't related to your HDD or your Ubuntu! I think your ISO isn't healthy or you didn't install it on USB properly.

Comment: You'll probably need to convert your disk from GPT to MBR-disc before installing XP. You can do this by booting from your Ubuntu installer, or some other bootdisc, and convert the disk.

Comment: I want to replace ubuntu with XP :) Ubuntu just isn't my cup of tea :/

And how do I convert my disk from GPT to MBR? :/ I'm such a noob lol, but I'd really really really appreciate the help :)

Comment: This is not a forum, and there's no need to edit your question to include the answer, or add "solved" to the title and so on. Just accept the answer that best helped you. Read the Help pages if in doubt.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your [Windows XP disc into a bootable USB format](http://www.komku.org/2009/09/wintoflash-guide-install-windows-xp.html#.UeQlnNvsI60). I used the quoted [WinToFlash tool](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) successfully for the same purpose about a month ago.

Once you have the Windows XP installer running you can [simply delete all existing content from your hard drive](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/instxpclean1_7.htm), then you won't have to mess with "changing MBR's" or anything else like that.

Comment: I'll use WinToFlash and post the results! :) thanks for the support so far!!

Comment: [EDIT] Thank you guys! The WinToFlash tool helped me out! :) I am installing windowsXP as we speak :) <333

Comment: Glad to hear things are going well. If you feel this answer satisfies the requirement, don't forgot to hit the green "check mark" on this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Reallydesperate The steps don't mention it, but remember to disable USB booting when the setup is complete. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The message you are receiving indicates whatever utility you used to create your XP bootable USB device did not write a bootsector to it.

If you just copied the files from the XP cd to a USB drive and expected it to work, you were mistaken.  You need to make the USB device bootable.  There are other quirks in getting the XP installer to boot off of a USB device, so I'd take @dtmland's recommendation and use a utility that creates a bootable USB device.